# WP background file transfer, more than 25 files

Tags: c#, list, download, windows-phone, background-transfer

according to this topic

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202959(v=vs.105).aspx

I'm trying to download more than 25 mp3 files from a list, in background, I made lot of different tries, basically I tried to pass a list, remove the file downloaded and recall the function again... but doesn't work with app in background... maybe because it's a variable? should I store into isolated storage? here is the last code:

```
ObservableCollection<File> remoteFileList = new ObservableCollection<File>();

public void downloadList()
{
    if ((remoteFileList.Count > 0) && (BackgroundTransferService.Requests.Count() < 5))
    {
        File t = remoteFileList.First();
        BackgroundTransferRequest transfer = startDownload(t.Name);
        transfer.TransferProgressChanged += new EventHandler<BackgroundTransferEventArgs>(transfer_TransferProgressChanged);
        remoteFileList.Remove(t);
    }
}

public void transfer_TransferStatusChanged(object sender, BackgroundTransferEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundTransferRequest b = e.Request as BackgroundTransferRequest;
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(b.TransferStatus);
    ProcessTransfer(e.Request);
    downloadList();
}
```

Comment: _with no luck_... Could you give some details about the issues you are facing? Maybe you should also include some code sample and the exception you are getting (if any).

Comment: @AlexFilipovici I added the code, it works only with app in foreground, not with app in background. (if now looks better the question can you reopen it without I need to create new one please?, Thanks)

Comment: @ShaunWilde I create a kind of queue with the ObservableCollection, is there a proper method?  (if now looks better the question can you reopen it without I need to create new one please? Thanks!)

Comment: @ShaunWilde about the standard queue: "Each app is limited to 25 transfer requests in the queue at any time, "

Comment: A queue doesn't have to be in memory, create the queue and use isolated storage to store your data. You add items to the queue (append to table). Now when you start transfers you pop an item off the queue and send it to the transfer requests (you now control how many are in progress) when an item is done you pop another. If your app goes to sleep or the background task shuts down your queue is safe in isolated storage for next time. You may want to add "failed/timeout" download handling.

Comment: @ShaunWilde so I cannot download more than 25 files in once... I need at least start once the app before download the first 25 files

Comment: Have you considered using a background agent to do the work for you, or to take over downloading should you app go to sleep?

Comment: @ShaunWilde yes but I have to many limitations:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/54f4b6/periodic-and-resourceintensive-tasks-in-windows-phone-mango/
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202962(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

To pop items off the `BackgroundTransfer` queue, you need to call the `Remove()` method in the `BackgroundTransferService` class. You cannot have more than 25 requests in a queue without popping something out of it.